# iterate through rows if x push to another spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the script mostly working- except the data being pushed actually says "Range" I must be missing something- can you not set values across a range?

```js
function up4Grabs() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  var destsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MYID GOES HERE").getSheetByName('Items');
  var destLastRow = destsheet.getLastRow();
  var destRange = destsheet.getRange(1,9,destLastRow);
  
  var dataLastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet1.getRange(1,9,dataLastRow);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] > 0) { 
      var targetLastRow = destsheet.getLastRow() + 1;
      var test = destsheet.getRange(1,9,targetLastRow);
      sheet1.getvalues(test).setValues(sheet1.getRange(i+1,1,1,9))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `setValues()` *note: plural*, and make sure you're using `getValues()` on the range inside that `setValues()`. At the moment you're passing a range to `setValue()` which is why it's just setting "Range".

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Cannot find function getvalues in object Sheet. - updating my code trying your suggestion

Comment: I'll post the code example as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem:

`setValue()` setting "Range" rather than actual values.

---

#### Cause:

You're passing a range rather than a value to the `setValue()` in the first place.

---

#### Solution:

```
function up4Grabs() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Final');
  var destsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("MY ID GOES HERE").getSheetByName('Items');
  var destLastRow = destsheet.getLastRow();
  var destRange = destsheet.getRange(1,9,destLastRow);

  var dataLastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet1.getRange(1,9,dataLastRow);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] > 0) { 
      var targetLastRow = destsheet.getLastRow() + 1;
      var values = sheet1.getRange(i+1,1,1,9).getValues();
      destsheet.getRange(1,9,values.length,9).setValues(values);
    }
  }
}
```

Since you're setting the values of a whole range, you need to use `setValues()` rather than `setValue()`, *note: plural rather than singular.*  I've also added `getValues()` to the range you were already pulling, this returns the array of values within the range that can then be passed to `setValues()`.

Comment: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 5. (line 91, file "Code")

Comment: I've made a change to the code which has now defined your values in a separate variable, then calculated the size of the range against the size of your values array using `values.length`, please try again.

Comment: still seeing this error now regarding columns- The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 9 but the range has 1. (line 94, file "Code")

Comment: Are you using the most recent version in the answer? The range has 9 columns in the answer provided.

Comment: yes it is working now thanks!! Ill have to study your work and see where I made my mistakes!

Comment: It was an easy mistake to make, instead of passing values to `setValues()` you were passing a range, which is why it was setting "Range", not the values you were expecting.